# Game crashing all the time / PC freezes sometimes

Tags: windows-10, freeze, crash, gaming

Since about a month I have the problem that a game (Grand Theft Auto V) is crashing all the time. Sometimes the complete PC freezes too so that it displays the old image e.g. a few minutes ago (completely unresponsive, only restarting the PC helps). The time is not predictable, when it crashes. At one time it crashes after five minutes, another time it crashes after half an hour. But one thing is sure - it will crash.

I have contacted the Rockstar Support and they say they can't help me anymore. Things I did asked by the Rockstar Support:

- reinstalled the game and `Social Club` multiple times
- deleted game files in `AppData/Local/Rockstar Games/GTA V` and `Documents\Rockstar Games\Social Club`
- deleted `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\GTAVLauncher.exe` and restored via Steam option `Verify integrity of game files`
- `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth` and `sfc /scannow` multiple times
- uninstalled another app, which should be responsible for network timeouts/blocking
- switching to story mode/second character
- submitted the export of `msinfo32` including crash reports to the support
- changed firewall settings

Things I tried myself:

- played in `Safe Mode`
- changed graphics settings
- removed OC
- updated to latest Nvidia driver (436.15)
- updated Windows 10
- checked the event log, but there is no entry
- executed `memtest86` without problems
- made a stress test with `FurMark` without problems

I don't have expierenced similar problems in other games/apps.

System configuration:

- i5-6600K
- 16 GB RAM
- Nvidia GeForce GTX 780

Temperature is always OK.

`Launcher.log` from GTA V writes something like:

```
Reset failed with D3DERR_DEVICELOST. 
Game exited with code 0xc0000005 
Category:  5 (ERROR_CATEGORY_EXIT_CODE) 
Code:     -1073741819 (c0000005) 
Exit code 0xc0000005 indicates a game crash (STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION) 
Unable to clear in-file and out-file!
```

How can I find the cause of this error?

Comment: I would suggest you get a process dump when it crashes.  Create C:\dumps\ directory.  Download procdump.exe to it from Microsoft/Sysinternals.  In an admin prompt CD \dumps, then run `procdump -ma -i C:\dumps`.  Next time it crashes it should create one, possibly 2 files in C:\dumps\.  Maybe you could zip and share the file to be analyzed.  I'm surprised their support hasn't asked for a dump.  You can run `procdump -u` to unregister procdump once done.

Comment: @HelpingHand: Thanks for the tip. I'll post the results, if I have re-downloaded the game again (re-install). This will only take some time ...

Comment: @HelpingHand: Now I have a dump, but it is 6.4 GB in file size ... I have compressed it down to 1 GB. Hope this helps.

Comment: I get a 403 Forbidden from the Link 1 and Link 2 options.  The other one is going to take 8 hrs! Is Google Drive or One Drive and option? Thanks.

Comment: ok [another try](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19wjkWl9ZHNs2LcQQUZTn8ao0PRjCT8LB/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: That was much faster. I think you might need to go back to Rockstar Support and maybe provide them the link to the dump.  Here is the very basic overview of the dump:   https://pastebin.com/WK70zkFD Given the problematic stack, without the symbols for C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\GTA5.exe it's difficult to know what it's doing.  I hoped I'd be able to provide you more.

Comment: Thanks for your support. How do you read the dump? With Visual Studio and Windows Driver Kit? Does it help if one has access to GTA5.exe?